# Finding the parametric equation for a line that passes through a point and intersects two lines.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I'm at my wit's end with this problem: Find a parametric representation of the line $\ell$ which passes through the point $(3,2,-1)$ and intersects the lines
$$\ell_1:
    \left\{
      \begin{alignedat}{3}
         x & ={} & 1 +{} &s \\
         y & ={} &       &s \\
         z & ={} & -1+{} &s
      \end{alignedat}
    \right.
\qquad
\ell_2:
    \left\{
      \begin{alignedat}{3}
         x & ={} &10 +{} & 5&t \\
         y & ={} &5  +{}  & &t \\
         z & ={} &2  +{} & 2&t
      \end{alignedat}
    \right.\tag*{($s,t \in \mathbf{R}$)}
$$

I feel like this seems like a typical routine problem that shouldn't stump me like this, but  I can't for the life of me figure out a nice solution.

I've tried the following:

Given an orthonormal system $O\mathbf{e}_1\mathbf{e}_2\mathbf{e}_3$ and
$$
\begin{align*}
P:(3,2,-1) && Q:(1+s,s,-1+s) && R: (10+5t,5+t,2+2t),
\end{align*}
$$
we want to find a direction vector $\overrightarrow{QR}$ such that
$$
\overrightarrow{QR} = \overrightarrow{QP} + \overrightarrow{PR} = (\overrightarrow{OP} - \overrightarrow{OQ}) + (\overrightarrow{OR} - \overrightarrow{OP}) = \overrightarrow{OR}-\overrightarrow{OQ}.
$$
We want this vector to be parallel to $\overrightarrow{QP} = \overrightarrow{OP} - \overrightarrow{OQ}$
so that it hits all 3 points. Hence
$$
\overrightarrow{QR} = k \overrightarrow{QP}\tag*{($k\in\mathbf{R}$)}
$$
which gives us
\begin{align*}
\overrightarrow{QR}=\overrightarrow{OR}-\overrightarrow{OQ} &= (10+5t-1-s,5+t-s,2+2t+1-s) = \\
&=(9+5t-s,5+t-s,3+2t-s) = k(2-s,2-s,-s)
\end{align*}
iff
$$
    \left\{
      \begin{alignedat}{4}
        9 & +{} &        5t-s &   &{} ={} & &{} 2k-ks \\
        5 & +{} &        t-s  &   &{} ={} & &{} 2k-ks \\
        3 & +{} & 2t-s        &   &{} ={} & &{} -ks
      \end{alignedat}
    \right.
$$
and I have no clue how to solve a system that looks like this, but solving it in Mathematica gives me the parameters $s=-2$ and $t=-1$.We then have
\begin{align*}
Q(-2): (-1,-2,-3) && R(-1):(5,4,0), 
\end{align*}
and given an arbitrary point $S: (x,y,z)$ on the line and the coordinates for the direction vector, we can then find the line's parametric equation with the following equation:
\begin{align*}
\overrightarrow{QS}&=\lambda\overrightarrow{QR}=\lambda(\overrightarrow{OR} - \overrightarrow{OQ}) =\lambda(6,6,3) =\\
 &=\overrightarrow{OS} - \overrightarrow{OQ}=(x+1,y+2,z+3)
\end{align*}
hence the line
$$\ell_3:
    \left\{
      \begin{alignedat}{3}
         x & ={} &-1 +{} & 6&\lambda \\
         y & ={} &-2  +{}  & 6&\lambda \\
         z & ={} &-3  +{} & 3&\lambda
      \end{alignedat}
    \right.\tag*{($\lambda \in \mathbf{R}$)}
$$
This solution looks very "all over the place" and I'm not even confident in the steps or the solution, but I've verified it in Mathematica and it is a solution.

The conclusion is that I'm looking for a neater solution and some insight to the problem. I've played around with the lines $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ and the plane that they span with the point $P$, but I don't really know how to proceed from there. My intuition tells me that I have to use that plane in some way.

Comment: Here's an idea: if you take the union of all the lines that pass through $P$ and intersect $\ell_1$, you get (essentially) a plane.  Now consider the relationship between that plane and $\ell_2$.

Comment: About "I have no clue how to solve a system that looks like this": if you subtract the third equation from the first two, you get a system of two linear equations in the two variables $t, k$ that you can solve; then plug the solution into the third equation.

Comment: I see now how the system of equations is solved through normal Gauss-Jordan elimination. However, I still don't know how to utilize planes for this problem. I see visually how if I were to union all the lines that intersect $\ell_1$ it would form a plane. No matter what I do, I always end up having a similar system of equations where I solve for parameters that yield me a direction vector for the line passing through all points.

Comment: All the possible lines $\ell$ together form a plane (whose equation you presumably know how to work out).  One of these lines intersects $\ell_2$.  Where is that point of intersection?

Answer (score 1):

First, consider the plane $\Pi_1$ formed by $\ell$ and $\ell_1$. The vector $[1,1,1]$ is is along the line $\ell_1$ and thus in the plane $\Pi_1$. Putting $s=0$, the point $(1,0,-1)$ is on $\ell_1$ and hence on $\Pi_1$. The point $(3,2,-1)$ i s also in $\Pi_1.$ Subtracting coordinates, we see that the vector $[2,2,0]$ lies in the plane $\Pi_1$ so the cross-product $n_1=[1,1,1] \times [2,2,0]$ is normal to $\Pi_1$ and thus perpendicular to a vector in the direction of $\ell.$ Similarly, we can consider the plane $\Pi_2$ formed by $\ell$ and $\ell_2$ and find a vector $n_2$ normal to $\Pi_2$ and hence perpendicular to a vector in the direction of $\ell.$ Then the cross-product $n_1 \times n_2$ is in the direction of $\ell.$ Since $(3,2,-1)$ is on $\ell$, we can immediately write the parametric equation for $\ell$.

Comment: I forgot to mention that dot and cross products have not yet been studied for this problem.